# How to remove all "document.write(' ');" with beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How to remove all "document.write(' ');" from the `<table> </table>` using beautifulsoup:
i have next raw html

```
document.write('<table>');
document.write('
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="prod">
   some text
   </span>
  </td>
  ');
document.write('
  <td>
   <span class="prod">
    7.70.022
   </span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 ');
document.write('</table>');
```

I need in next result with beautifulsoup:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="prod">
   some text
   </span>
  </td>
  <td>
   <span class="prod">
    7.70
   </span>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use regexs to remove the parts you don't want and then parse it using beautifulsoup?

```
import re

data = """document.write('<table>');
document.write('
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="prod">
   some text
   </span>
  </td>
  ');
document.write('
  <td>
   <span class="prod">
    7.70.022
   </span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 ');
document.write('</table>');"""

pattern = re.compile(r"document\.write\('\n?([^']*?)(?:\n\s*)?'\);")
data = pattern.sub('\g<1>', data)
print data
```

*Output*

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="prod">
   some text
   </span>
  </td>
  <td>
   <span class="prod">
    7.70.022
   </span>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```